# Using Case in SQL for row-wise calculations

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

This is the query:

```
SELECT CASE Count(RADLD.request_id) 
         WHEN 0 THEN (SELECT Sum(Datediff(dd, rad.clarity_dt, Getdate()))) 
         ELSE (SELECT Sum(Datediff(dd, radld.clarity_dt, Getdate()))) 
       END 
FROM   ppa.request_add_details rad, 
       ppa.request_add_details_loop_details radld, 
       ppa.request req 
WHERE  radld.request_id = rad.request_id 
       AND radld.request_id = req.request_id 
       AND rad.clarity_dt IS NOT NULL 
       AND ( rad.recomm_dt IS NULL ) 
       AND rad.modified_by !=- 1 
       AND rad.request_id = req.request_id 
       AND ( ( radld.loop_sequence = CASE 
                                     WHEN radld.loop_sequence IS NOT NULL THEN 1 
                                     END ) 
              OR ( radld.loop_sequence IS NULL ) )
```

This is how I would like it to work: If for a request_id,entry in radld thn is found, it should go for

```
select sum(datediff(dd,radld.clarity_dt,getdate()))
```

and if no corresponding entry is found in radld then it should go for

`select sum(datediff(dd,rad.clarity_dt,getdate()))` ..

What is actually happening is: If for any request the record is found in **radld**.. then it will apply `select sum(datediff(dd,radld.clarity_dt,getdate()))` to all the records.

Please help

Comment: `mysql` *and* `sql server`?

Comment: `CASE` is SQL Server is an **expression** that can return a value - it is **NOT** a flow control statement that can execute code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your query, you have done inner join, it means it will returns only those requests which are in all tables (rad, radld and req). So there will be never case like `Count(RADLD.request_id)` will be 0. So all records will have same result. You should check it with `LEFT or RIGHT JOIN` and by checking NULL data instead of COUNT. So you can get correct result what you want.

Try something like below :

```
SELECT CASE WHEN radld.request_id IS NOT NULL 
            THEN (SELECT Sum(Datediff(dd, radld.clarity_dt, Getdate()))) 
            ELSE (SELECT Sum(Datediff(dd, rad.clarity_dt, Getdate()))) END 
FROM   ppa.request req 
LEFT JOIN ppa.request_add_details_loop_details radld ON req.request_id = radld.request_id
LEFT JOIN ppa.request_add_details rad ON radld.request_id = rad.request_id
WHERE rad.clarity_dt IS NOT NULL 
AND rad.recomm_dt IS NULL
AND rad.modified_by !=- 1 
AND ((radld.loop_sequence = 1) OR (radld.loop_sequence IS NULL))
```

Comment: from ppa.request req inner join ppa.request_add_details rad on 
rad.request_id = req.request_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN PPA.REQUEST_ADD_DETAILS_LOOP_DETAILS radld

Comment: The query is working fine but stil as soon as the CASE finds a entry in RADLD, it starts working on "Sum(Datediff(dd, radld.clarity_dt, Getdate()))".. and avoid checking the CASE of other requests.